# referencing a table in a dataset by name

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, dataset

I have a dataset which contains two tables 'AdvBusiness' and 'AdvertiserCategory' index 0 and 1 respectively.  Reading the documentation I am under the impression that I should also be able to reference a table by going myDataSet.Tables("AdvBusiness") but this throws an error:
"cannot be used like a method" I am just wondering how do you reference a table by its name rather than the index?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in C# you'll use

```
myDataSet.Tables["AdvBusiness"]
```

Notice the difference in using the "[]" instead of "()"

Comment: I hate when i have to work in VB.NET and I still use [] out of habit.

Comment: note for others. you have to use `dataset.tables.add(data table)` for this to work. If you populate dataset directly, without adding table, you can't reference it by name.